# Good book about sound basics

Tags: sound, books

Can anyone suggest a good introductory book explaining basics on how sound is created from the math & physics point of view?

Comment: Why a book? Is this link helpful: http://method-behind-the-music.com/mechanics/physics/ or maybe this: http://www.yale.edu/ynhti/curriculum/units/2000/5/00.05.10.x.html

Comment: Or what about this: http://www.lowellcross.com/scitech/sound/

Comment: I think you'll fid some nice stuff digging the archives here: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions?pagesize=50&sort=votes

Comment: www.dspguide.com or Gareth Loy - Musimathics

Answer (score 1):

what i found very useful is [Syntorial](http://www.syntorial.com), very awesome way to learn how to master synths